# CKEditor + KCEditor upload error

Tags: file-upload, ckeditor, kcfinder

I spent the whole day but was unable to find a solution.
I installed CKEditor and KCFinder, everything works fine except for one: when I want to upload a image from the ["Browse Server" window](http://prntscr.com/80e7fv) file dosen't upload and result is ["Unknow error"](http://prntscr.com/80e6e2).
When I upload from simple tag ["Upload"](http://prntscr.com/80e81j) the file is uploading but is not created a thumb and when I browse the server i can't see the thums of images, only icons of pic and name.

upload:

`'uploadURL' => "http://domain.com/uploads/",
 'uploadDir' => "../../../uploads/",`

config:

```
CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '<?=$GLOBALS['_st_']['urlTree']?>libraries/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '<?=$GLOBALS['_st_']['urlTree']?>libraries/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '<?=$GLOBALS['_st_']['urlTree']?>libraries/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '<?=$GLOBALS['_st_']['urlTree']?>libraries/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '<?=$GLOBALS['_st_']['urlTree']?>libraries/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '<?=$GLOBALS['_st_']['urlTree']?>libraries/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
```

when: `$GLOBALS['_st_']['urlTree']` is dinamic something like '../' in one or more steps